# Inverse matrix not computing

Tags: matrix, inverse

Hi just wondering why my Inverse of matrix will not compute? I don't believe its wrapped from //MatrixForm because I copied it by hand into a new document and it still would not work.

Any ides?[image]

> > `m2 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, Exp[L], Exp[0*L], Exp[0*L]}, {-1, 1, 0, 
> >        0}, {0, Exp[L], 0*Exp[-w2*L], 0*Exp[w2*L]}}`
> >     `Y = {0, f, 0, 0}`
> >     `c = Inverse[m2].Y`

Comment: The error says your matrix is singular... this means there is no inverse.

Comment: And why would you keep in terms such as `Exp[0 * L]`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it in MatrixForm you'll see that you have two columns that are identical, and therefore the matrix is rank deficient and not invertible.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & e^L & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & e^L & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$